# Pairwise distance and residual calculation

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

I have a code for calculating the pairwise distances and the residuals of my data (X, Y, Z). Data is quite large (average of 7000 rows) and so my interest is code efficiency. My initial code is

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import, numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)
npoints, cols = data.shape

pwdistance = np.zeros((npoints, npoints))
pwresidual = np.zeros((npoints, npoints))
for i in range(npoints):
    for j in range(npoints):
        pwdistance[i][j] = np.sqrt((data[:,0][i]-data[:,0][j])**2 + (data[:,1][i]-data[:,1][j])**2)
        pwresidual[i][j] = (data[:,2][i]-data[:,2][j])**2
```

With the `pwdistance`, I changed it to the following below which works extremely good.

```
pwdistance = squareform(pdist(data[:,:2]))
```

Is there a pythonic way of calculating my `pwresidual`, so I do not need to use a loop and to enable my code to run faster?

Comment: The comma in `import, numpy as np` is a typo, right?

Comment: I had the impression that CR was more strict than SO about the completeness of the code.  This example is not self contained, and cannot be tested without constructing data, and correcting at least one typo.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start by setting

```
col2 = data[:,2]
```

to avoid some repetition. (If I knew what was in the `data` array then maybe I could pick a better name, but all I have to go on is what was in the post.)

Now here are two possible approaches to computing `pwresidual`:

1. `pwresidual[i,j]` is the result of an operation on `col2[i]` and `col2[j]`. You might recognize this as being similar to an [*outer product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) in mathematics — except that the operation is subtraction rather than multiplication.

   But in NumPy every [*universal function*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) has an ["outer" counterpart](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer), and [`np.subtract`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html#numpy.subtract) is a universal function, so all we need is:

   ```
    pwresidual = np.subtract.outer(col2, col2) ** 2
   ```
2. Alternatively, we can use NumPy's [*broadcasting*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-broadcasting) mechanism, combined with [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) to ensure every pair of items gets operated on:

   ```
    pwresidual = (col2[:,np.newaxis] - col2[np.newaxis,:]) ** 2
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Usually in `numpy` we write

```
pwresidual[i][j] = (data[:,2][i]-data[:,2][j])**2
```

as

```
pwresidual[i,j] = (data[i,2] - data[j,2])**2
```

Here's it's a style issue more than a functional one, but sometimes the distinction is important.

But as Gareth shows you don't need to iterate - just broadcast

```
pwresidual = (data[:,None,2]-data[None,:,2])**2
```

It subtracts a row array from a column array:

```
In [95]: data=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [96]: data
Out[96]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
In [97]: data[:,None,2]
Out[97]: 
array([[ 2],
       [ 5],
       [ 8],
       [11]])
In [98]: data[None,:,2]
Out[98]: array([[ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
In [99]: data[:,None,2]-data[None,:,2]
Out[99]: 
array([[ 0, -3, -6, -9],
       [ 3,  0, -3, -6],
       [ 6,  3,  0, -3],
       [ 9,  6,  3,  0]])
```

as for the other expression:

```
pwdistance[i][j] = np.sqrt((data[:,0][i]-data[:,0][j])**2 + (data[:,1][i]-data[:,1][j])**2)

pwdistance[i, j] = np.sqrt((data[i,0]-data[j,0])**2 + (data[i,1]-data[j,1])**2)

pwdistance = np.sqrt( (data[:,None,0]-data[None,:,0])**2 + (data[:,None,1]-data[None,:,1])**2)
```

Together we can do

```
temp = (data[:,None,:] - data[None,:,:])**2
pwdistance = np.sqrt( temp[:,:,0] + temp[:,:,1])
pwresidual = temp[:,:,2]
```

WIth the above test `data`:

```
In [101]: pwdistance
Out[101]: 
array([[  0.        ,   4.24264069,   8.48528137,  12.72792206],
       [  4.24264069,   0.        ,   4.24264069,   8.48528137],
       [  8.48528137,   4.24264069,   0.        ,   4.24264069],
       [ 12.72792206,   8.48528137,   4.24264069,   0.        ]])
In [102]: pwresidual
Out[102]: 
array([[ 0,  9, 36, 81],
       [ 9,  0,  9, 36],
       [36,  9,  0,  9],
       [81, 36,  9,  0]])
```

Comment: I think that using `np.newaxis` (instead of `None`) in index expressions makes it clearer what the intention is.